# If/Else statement troubles (android)

Tags: android, if-statement

I've been having some troubles to get an IF/ELSE statement working.

I have the following code:

```
    File fileOnSD=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();    
    String storagePath = fileOnSD.getAbsolutePath();
    Bitmap BckGrnd = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(storagePath + "/oranjelanbg.png");
    ImageView BackGround = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);        
    BackGround.setImageBitmap(BckGrnd);
    if (){

    }else{
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

And I'm trying to achieve to following.
My app downloads an image to the phone and uses this as a background.
But the picture is not downloaded yet when u run the app for the first time, so there must be some text instead.
The text is invisible by default and I want to make it visible when the image is still downloading and not placed yet.

What expression should I use in the IF statement to check if the image is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if (BckGrnd != null){
          BackGround.setImageBitmap(BckGrnd);
    }else{
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

**Better Solution:**

Use **AyncTask** for Downloading Image:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> loadingTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {                                     
        TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {                 
           // Download Image Here
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  
           BackGround.setImageBitmap(BckGrnd);
           text1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    };          
    loadingTask.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks your first awnser worked like a charm, the whole download thing is already in a Asynctask so the first awnser will do just fine! Thanks!

Comment: Dont have enough rep for that yet :D